# Laravel Vue: Axios 401 error on form submit

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a modal where I can create/edit user. But when I click on the submit button I got a 401 error.

The method looks like this:

```
sendUserData(){
                axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                    },
                    id: this.id,
                    name: this.name,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.$emit('userSaved')
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
```

The api.php looks like this:

```
Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');

});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('saveUser', 'UserController@saveUser');
});
```

If I console.log the token I got a valid JSON token

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to use `web.php` instead of `api.php` ? Maybe it's the first step to solve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your axios function is not well formatted. It should be like this:

```php
axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
    id: this.id,
    name: this.name,
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.$emit('userSaved')
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```